# Excluding category from loop not working

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop

I'm listing out all posts of a custom post type on a page. I want to remove one category from the query as I'm using it to categorize posts with gated content and as such don't want them to display.

Here's my query:

```
$category = get_cat_ID( 'Gated' );
$exclude = '-'.$category;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'resource',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat'            => $exclude,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But what ends up being `'cat' => -46` doesn't seem to be doing anything at all, the posts Categorized as "Gated" still display.

From what I've read in the codex etc, I feel like I'm doing this correctly. But apparently I'm not? I've run out of different ways to tweak this. Please help!

(FYI `$exclude` prints out the right category ID + `-`, and I have tried manually entering the `-46`)

Comment: With the exception of the missing `$` in the `args` variable which I'm assuming is a mistype, your code runs fine on my test site. You may have a `pre_get_posts` affecting the query elsewhere / not shown here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this works. And yes, the missing `$` was a mistype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Howdy_McGee confirmed the code works I had to look elsewhere. I noticed I had a duplicate post with the same title (that WASN'T categorized as "Gated") that was always displaying. So I didn't notice when the Gated one was disappearing. >.<